# Zuul pass information to other microservices

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have an angular application built on microservices. Zuul is my gateway. When the user first logs in, he is routed to the angular app if authenticated. Once the user is in the angular application, I need the ability to call another microservice passing in the user information collected at login. What options do I have to make this information available to the other service.

One option I could think of is have the gateway store the information in a cookie, have the angular application read that information from the cookie and pass it to the other microservice. Since the cookie can be tampered, I am thinking that may not be the right way.

Zuul filter? may not work as the services as stateless, I cannot use the session to store that information.

Any other options for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Zuul pre filter to set the user data on the header and send  to the next microservice